# Looking for HTML 5 CMS Form Controls for Kentico 9+

Tags: html, webforms, kentico

We're looking for first-class HTML 5 CMS Form Controls for Kentico 9+, meaning control/s that integrate with the Kentico Form Builder and Fields tabs seamlessly, and that express useful related settings, for example to affect available attributes and achieve more UI flexibility (than Kentico has classically supported out-of-the-box).

A quick search in the Marketplace finds [this control](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/html5-input-form-control) (supports Kentico 9, 10. Missing 11).

It would not be hard to roll our own, however if the wheel is already invented, or if there are pointers to pre-existing dev notes that are useful for this case, then those items will help us to assess using HTML 5 form controls in Kentico.

Note a lot of the focus is on the HTML 5 input element's [type attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#sec-states-of-the-type-attribute).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the controls you shared would be the suggested (if you don't want to create your own).  There is not a v11 because v11 already has them included.

Comment: Thank you Brenden, also for the pointer about Kentico 11's HTML5 form support. https://docs.kentico.com/k11/custom-development/developing-form-controls/working-with-html5-form-inputs